# How do I edit nested state of dynamicly generated state (using useState hook)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I'm trying to modify a nested property of a useState, but I'm struggling to do it in this case:

1. The component receives a prop "order" which has many items (line_items), which are the products within that order
2. A useEffect iterates through the line_items and generates an array which is stored in an "editOrders" state

   useEffect(() => {
   if (order.line_items && order.line_items.length) {
   setEditOrders([]);

   ```
    order.line_items.forEach(item => {
        setEditOrders(prevState => [
            ...prevState,
            {
                name: item.name,
                price: item.total,
                quantity: item.quantity,
                weight: ''
            }
        ])
      })
    }
      }, [])
   ```
3. The items in the array state "editOrders" is displayed in a form

   ```
                 <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmitChanges(e)}>

                    {

                            (editOrders.map((item, index) => (
                                <div style={{
                                    display: "flex",
                                    flexDirection: "row",
                                    padding: "10px 30px",
                                    alignItems: "center"
                                }}>
                                    <h5 style={{flex: 8}}>{item.name}</h5>

                                    <MDBox pt={2} pb={1} px={1} sx={{flex: 3}}>
                                        <MDInput
                                            type="text"
                                            variant="standard"
                                            label="Gewicht"
                                            disabled={loading && true}
                                            onChange={(e) => setEditOrders(e.target.value)}
                                            value={item.weight}
                                        />
                                    </MDBox>


                     /////// THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS

                                    <MDBox pt={2} pb={1} px={1} sx={{flex: 1}}>
                                        <FormControl variant="standard">
                                            <Select
                                                value="kg"
                                                style={{height: 44}}
                                                label="Einheit"
                                                endAdornment={
                                                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                                                        <ArrowDropDown fontSize="medium" color="standard"/>
                                                    </InputAdornment>
                                                }
                                                onChange={(e) => setEditOrders(prevState => ({
                                                ...prevState,
                                                editOrders[index].weight: e.target.value
                                            }))} 
                                                disabled={loading && true}
                                            >
                                                <MenuItem value="g">g</MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem value="kg">kg</MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem value="ml">ml</MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem value="cl">cl</MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem value="l">l</MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem value="Stück">Stück</MenuItem>
                                            </Select>
                                        </FormControl>
                                    </MDBox>


                                </div>
                            )))

                    }


                    <MDBox pt={2} pb={3} px={3}>
                        <MDButton type="submit" variant="gradient" color="info" disabled={disabled}>
                            "Create"
                        </MDButton>
                    </MDBox>
                </form>
   ```

Since it's a dynamically generated list, depending on the {order} prop, my goal is to change the state of that particular item in the list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first duplicate the array, then you can safely mutate the new array.

```
onChange={(e) => setEditOrders(prevState => ({
  const prevOrder = prevState[index];
  const nextState = [...prevState];
  nextState[index] = { ...prevOrder, weight: e.target.value };
  return nextState;
}))}
```

Comment: Worked very well, just one correction, I had to remove the parentheses after prevState:

setEditOrders(prevState => {
            const prevOrder = prevState[index];
            const nextState = [...prevState];
            nextState[index] = {...prevOrder, weight: e.target.value};
            return nextState;
        })

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this by writing a function that gets the index and the value and updating the state like this:

```js
const handleOnChange = (event, index) => {
  setEditOrders((prevState) => {
    const newState = [...prevState];
    newState[index].weight = event.target.value;
    return newState;
  )
)
```

And then use it like this:

```js
<MDBox pt={2} pb={1} px={1} sx={{flex: 1}}>
  <FormControl variant="standard">
    <Select
      value="kg"
      style={{height: 44}}
      label="Einheit"
      endAdornment={
        <InputAdornment position="end">
          <ArrowDropDown fontSize="medium" color="standard"/>
        </InputAdornment>
      }
      onChange={(event) => handleOnChange(event, index)} 
      disabled={loading && true}
    >
      <MenuItem value="g">g</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="kg">kg</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="ml">ml</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="cl">cl</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="l">l</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="Stück">Stück</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
</MDBox>
```